# Decrypting url string with given password and salt

Tags: string, security, encryption, passwords, salt

this will be somehow vague, because I don't know how to properly approach this issue.

A third party has given me a URL with encrypted data in it. I need to decrypt it and use the data from the URL string in my form.

The Url looks something like this:

https://url?data1=5y3Dg55FlK9wj1kJQYL6jKxyK3%2bXdXzYzc%2fgp9o%3d&data2=0P7Fsdf4LeuTosdf3kwwA%3d%3d

All I've got is a decrypting password and a decrypting salt. It is supposed to be done with an AES encryption in 128bit. I absolutely don't know how I combine the password + salt and test if I can get real data by decrypting one string.

Note: The strings are url encoded.

CAn somebody push me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: That's too much that you don't know. We usually don't guess around.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, the encrypted data is the URI staring after data1. You said you have the password and thr hash, now all you need is to put that information into a decryption function for aes128. If you're looking for help with this step, we will need to know what language you're using.

After decryption, you'll get an urlencoded string and then you just need to un-urlencode it to get the original data.

Comment: If you look closely there are two items in the URL query string: `data1` and `data2` and each has a Base64 encoded value. The entire query string needs to be URL decoded, separate the too data values, each needs to be Base64 decoded and then each needs to be decrypted.

Answer (score -1):

What code have you already tried?  What language are you using?  Is the value of "data1" in the URL the encrypted password - if so, where do you get the salt value?  Please provide more information - I don't know enough to even push you in the right direction currently.